# Data structures for tracking changes to object identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, tracking, propagation

I need to implement a system for tracking changes to unique numerical object identifiers. The environment that the system will operate in is very restrictive so all of the convenient enterprise class RDBMS methods of approaching the problem are off the table. That means enabling built in change tracking, or built in auditing or writing output to a log file or using triggers on the tables or the like wont be part of the solution. The changes need to be stored in an 'insert only' transaction table that will be written and managed at the application level.

The objects that I need to track changes on can behave in two ways:

- a single object can be divided into two new objects
- two objects can be merged together to form a single object

For a given collection of objects, object ID's are unique long integers. When an object is divided (split) the ID assigned to the subject object is retired and replaced by two new ones. Thus when object 27 is split, it is replaced with object 57 and 58 with 57 and 58 being the next available numbers to obtain from that particular sequence.

Similarly, when two objects are merged into one, the subject object ids are retired and replaced with the next available number in the sequence. Thus when object 85 and object 227 are merged together they are replaced by object 357 which is the next available unused number in the sequence. In a merge operation, we can keep the attributes associated with only one of the two parents, so the user will select which ones will be retained at merge time which in this case is either 85 or 227. This choice needs to be stored for later
use.

The transaction table needs to store the complete history of object splits and merges. There can be no limit to the number of splits and merges that an object can
be the subject of.

I'm looking for suggestions on a SQL data structure that can be used to efficiently store the transactions with a single table if possible.

Once the transaction table structure is defined, I need to be able to query it with SQL so that I can retrieve the full ID lineage of any particular ID that was involved in a split
or merge transaction. In this case things are not quite as restrictive, so we can setup one or more views on the transaction data as needed or write new tables etc. as required. Recursive SQL can be used to query and display ID lineages.

Once the transaction recording has been defined, the next requirement is to asynchronously propagate the changed ID's to one or more related tables.

Split Example

Parent Table ID 27 is split into ID 57 and ID 58. In the related table, the record
with ID 27 would be deleted and replaced with two (identical to ID 27) new records that carry ID's 57 and 58 respectively.

Merge Example

Parent Table ID 327 and ID 959 are merged into ID 1023. In the related table the records carrying ID 327 and ID 959 would be deleted and replaced with a new one marked 1023. The attribute values defined in the new record would be based on the choice stored with the original merge transaction.

Your suggestions are very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the most straightforward way:

```
part1_id part2_id composed_id is_split
```

where `is_split` is true for splits and false for merges. In case of a merge, the attributes of `part1_id` get preserved (this removes and ambiguity). In case of a split, `part1_id < part2_id` must hold.

This should be enough for simple and efficient storing of the data, the retrieval is a bit complicated as you have to follow an arbitrary long chain and look the `id` in all three fields.

But there's about nothing you could do against it as an `id` can participate in an arbitrary long chain. Maybe a table like

```
in1_id in2_id out1_id out2_id
```

could be a bit better for retrieval. For a merge, both `in`s are used and only one `out` (you get the idea, right?). Just add all needed constrains in order to fight the redundancy of this representation.